# HTML5 Canvas lines not having consistent width

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm drawing a rectangle on HTML5 canvas using the below code:

```
canvasId = $('#objectData').find('#miImages '+imageId+' .imageContainer canvas').attr("id");
canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.rect(coordinateArray[0],coordinateArray[1],coordinateArray[2],coordinateArray[3]);  
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = "DarkBlue";
context.stroke();
```

The problem is that the two vertical lines are a lot thicker than the two horizontal lines, what is causing this?

EDIT: I have height set at `89` and width set at `802`. When I remove the height the rectangle no longer distorts.

Comment: What are the values in your coordinateArray--and could they be non-integers?  I'm not getting any distortion at all using (11,10,150,100) in IE,Chrome,FF.

Comment: The vales input can change but an example is `3,65,43,60`

Comment: I'm not getting any distortion using those coordinates.  Are you viewing on a mobile device or tv monitor?

Comment: No I'm viewing it on my laptop.

Comment: See edit to original post.

Comment: So, you're drawing the rectangle off the bottom of the canvas: top=43 + height=60 -> rectangle bottom=103 with canvas.height=89 the rect bottom is off canvas?

Comment: @markE I'm not sure what you're asking me.

Answer (score 0):

I was sizing my canvas with CSS instead of JavaScript which was scaling the canvas rather than actually resizeing it. I fixed this using the below code.

```
function applyCanvasSize(){
  $("#objectData img").on('load', function(){
    var theHeight = $(this).height();
    var canvasId = $(this).next('canvas').attr('id');
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    if (canvas.getContext) { 
      canvas.width = 802;
      canvas.height = theHeight;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late but had the same problem.
Somewhere in my code, I was changing the size of the canvas using style.width and style.height. Directly use width and height instead. Without "px" in the end (thus only accepts pixels ?). You wont get the distortion anymore.